# Connecting a webservice - using IP instead of the machine name

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I've written a web service and hosted it in my local system using IIS. So when i connect to the webservice using http://localhost/server/service.asmx as the URL i'm getting the desired results (aka everything works like charm). But when i use http://192.168.14.56/server/service.asmx i'm not able to get any of the results.

But when i try to open the service in the browser both of the URLs are working fine. I'm using a third party component which is hosted as a web service. So i'm not able to debug it.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like the component is not able to do a lookup on the ip address hence difficulty in resolving the address...

Comment: Okie. Leave out that component. Does it normally work with web services? IP instead of name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okie, it was a total mess up with my system. I detached it and reattached it in the domain (as i'm no good in troubleshooting them) and everything worked fine. Thanks for your replies guys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to supply the port number in where the url for the webservice is located when using the third party component, it could be something like this: http://192.168.14.56**:12345**/server/service.asmx *as an example*, or that there is something blocking the third party component from accessing the web...

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I'm hosting it in the default port. No port changes. And it is not connecting to any web since it is being hosted locally.